# How do I translate "both medicines and foods have common origin"?

Tags: translation

I am trying to translate the sentence

> both medicines and foods have common origin

into simplified Chinese using different translation apps etc. and get weirdly different answers.

Comment: The answer is 食药同源.

Comment: I think the more common term is 药食同源. If you google 食药同源, most pages show 药食同源, neither 食药同源 nor 医食同源.

Answer (score 2):

> *"both medicines and foods have common origin"*

It is called [医食同源](http://www.n-mart.com.tw/docs/a10.htm), and it is a common expression (more literary).

In colloquial form, it would be "医药与食物有共通的源头"

Medicines can be food; Food can be medicines